# uploading file permissions in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, permissions

I am uploadig a file.

while uploading i am creating a folder with 0777 permission and upload the selected file into that particular folder.

Its get uploaded correctly.

but the problem is, when i delete the uploaded file it shows permission denied.

what to do??..

my code like,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        mkdir("../games/$gname",0777);
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['name'])
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], "../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]."");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add permission for file using `chmod` after you upload the file

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    mkdir("../games/$gname",0777); 
    //or create directory with recursive permision 
    //mkdir("../games/$gname",0777, true); 
    if($_FILES['fileupload']['name'])
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], "../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]."");
chmod ("../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"], 0777);
    }
}
```

Comment: after you upload the file check the permission for that file manually using FTP or Filezilla

Answer (score 0):

I am Just Using this to change permission,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    mkdir("../games/$gname",0777); 

    if($_FILES['fileupload']['name'])
    {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], "../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]."");
        exec("chmod 777 ../games/".$gname."/.*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all create folder with 0775 and not 0777 as a security measure as 0777 is world writeable and it is not recommended..
and then try this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        mkdir("../games/$gname",0775);
        if($_FILES['fileupload']['name'])
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileupload"]["tmp_name"], "../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"]."");

@chmod("../games/".$gname."/".$_FILES["upload"]["name"], 0775);

        }
}
```

Also, you may share your code for deleting the uploaded file..